# INET 3.4 cannot open libINET.so

Tags: omnet++, inet, veins

Recently, I downloaded OMNET 5 in Ubuntu 14.04 & automatically downloaded INET 3.4. When I am trying to run any example in INET the follwing error appears:

> <!> Warning: opp_run: Cannot check library ../../src/INET: ../../src//libINET.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> <!> Error during startup: Cannot load library '../../src//libINET.so': ../../src//libINET.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I tried to reconfigure the INET framework and also downloaded INET manually but I still facing the same problem.
Could anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably did not build `INET`. Select `Project` and `Build Project`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that inet didn't build properly due to some missing system libraries, after checking the build log and installing the missing system libraries the build went ok and i could run examples without any problems